# nginx doesn't listen to any port at all

Tags: nginx

I installed nginx in my server but it didn't work.
I used `netstat -tlpn| grep nginx` to find nginx port but it didn't pass me anything. and when I used `netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN` there was no nginx running at all but when I use `systemctl status nginx.service` I get a response.

```
  Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Active: active (running) since Sun 2020-11-01 12:42:14 +0330; 1s ago
  Process: 1300 ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2997 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2994 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2992 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/rm -f /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2999 (nginx)
    Tasks: 9
   Memory: 7.1M
   CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           ├─2999 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
           ├─3000 nginx: worker process
           ├─3001 nginx: worker process
           ├─3002 nginx: worker process
           ├─3003 nginx: worker process
           ├─3004 nginx: worker process
           ├─3005 nginx: worker process
           ├─3006 nginx: worker process
           └─3007 nginx: worker process
```

and by the way, there is no app listening to port 80 but I have a docker container listening to port 443
and I try to change the listening port from 80 to 3200 in site-available/default but it didn't change anything

Comment: is the nginx running in docker? if yes, it's better not running it as a service.

Comment: no it's not. it's running as service

Comment: I removed the `docker` tag since it's irrelevant for this issue

Answer (score 0):

you can take a look to see what application is listening to port 80 with :
 `netstat -tulpn| grep 80`
and as Stefano said, you can once stop your docker container to see if it goes well or not.
if you want to use Nginx in order to proxy requests to Docker containers, you can also use the Nginx container instead

Comment: there is no application that listening to port 80

Comment: what happens when you type: ` nginx -t ` in your CMD ?

Comment: Do you have any config to test if Nginx truly proxies the request?